# dojo multiple onclicks with different function calls

Tags: onclick, dojo, dom-events, js-amd

while converting Dojo Non-AMD JS to AMD, finding difficulty with event
 handling
we have many buttons,span & div's with different events with multiple actions.
so want to know should we use `on` or `connect` & how to use it to multiple element events?

```
 <span onclick="a.abShow(); t.T1(); p.show();">

 <span onclick="a.test(); setTimeout(a.test1(),100)">
 <td onclick="ab.test7(); t.test();">

 Button('gallery', 'e.Refresh();a.test();','');

 ........
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily run multiple actions on an event using the `dojo/on` module:

> dojo/on is a general-purpose event handler module for DOM nodes and other event emitting objects, providing normalized event listening and event dispatching functionality.

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/on.html#dojo-on

```js
require(['dojo/on', 'dojo/domReady!'], function (on) {

  on(dojo.byId('my-span'), 'click', function (e) {
    alert('I throw an alert');
    alert('And do it again');
    alert('And again');
  });

  on(dojo.byId('my-other-span'), 'click', function (e) {
    alert('I throw an alert');
    alert('And do it again');
    alert('And again');
  });

});
```

```html
<script type="application/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<span id="my-span">Click me!</span>
<span id="my-other-span">Click me too!</span>
```